# On change event listener in Google Apps Script using forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm kinda beginner in the Google Apps Script. Thanks for any help on this.

I'm trying to get values from form and I would like to get it dynamically, ie. if a user chooses value from linear scale question on the fly it goes into my script function in Google Apps Script which adds dynamically another section to my form. Something like on change listener? 
Is that possible using Google Apps Script?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically show / hide form items using Google App Script in Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563199/dynamically-show-hide-form-items-using-google-app-script-in-google-form)

Comment: Thank you for that. This is indeed an answer to my question, but it was posted 4 years ago. Has anything been changed from that time?

Comment: You can view their [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/) to view specific details of functionality changes. I would argue that dynamic form updating would qualify as a major product revision and would be noted in both blog posts and at least a quarter page of documentation. (The answer is, no, it has not changed).

Comment: OK, thank you for the answer!